# Desktop sharing - which port to forward?

Tags: 11.10, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I'm trying to share my desktop with the integrated tool *Desktop Sharing*
Is there ports to forward on the router, and which ones ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ubuntu 11.10, I turned on the 'Desktop Sharing' application that comes with the OS and found that these ports are opened on my computer:

```
5800/tcp open  vnc-http
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

They seem to be just the VNC ports.

If you want to verify this for yourself, download this tool from the repository called **nmap**:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

When you install that and have the 'Desktop Sharing' on, run this command in your terminal:

```
sudo nmap localhost
```

By default, this will show you all the TCP based ports that are opened. If you don't see any ports open, you might want to look at your local firewall by doing the following command:

```
sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
```

This will only list what rules are currently being used on your system.

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This is drawing on my memory from about 10 years ago so may be wrong? I seem to recall it's port 22.

Comment: That would be by default the SSH protocol. Not VNC. The default one for VNC is 5500, 5800, 5900 and well around those numbers. Here is more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers